# Hex-Ray Decompiler: inline function not recognized

Tags: ida, hexrays, decompiler

While trying to decompile an application with Hex-Ray 7.0, I stumbled upon the problem that in nearly all cases, what seems to be a certain inline function will not be recognised, which bloats the code base and makes it really hard to read.
The function seems to be strcpy or something similar. Is there a way to have the Decompiler change the mentioned parts to an inline function? Or can I do it manually somehow?
Here's a screenshot to illustrate my issue:[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: That's `strcpy` or `strcat`. Hexrays doesn't seem to recognize it in some compilers (I used to see this in very old Watcom executables, it recognizes it fine in most MSVC binaries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's extremely common. Sometimes Hex-Rays recognizes these patterns, sometimes it doesn't. Get used to recognizing them visually, writing a comment if necessary, and moving on.